# Event Trigger not working on Storyboard

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged, eventtrigger

I was just hoping you could help fill a gap in my WPF knowledge.

(please forgive the generic naming, not sure if it helps)

I've a custom object, MyObject, that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. It has a property called MyCustomProperty, as follows;

```
public int MyCustomProperty
{
 get { return this._myCustomProperty; }
 set
 {
  if (this._myCustomProperty == value)
    return;
  this._myCustomProperty= value;
  OnPropertyChanged("MyCustomProperty");
 }
}
```

This all works. 
In my WPF app I have these 3 functions;

```
private void DoStuff()
{
   AddItemsToCanvas();
   ChangeValues();
}

private void AddItemsToCanvas()
{
   DataTemplate dt = (DataTemplate)FindResource("myDataTemplate");
   foreach (MyObject temp in ListOfMyObjects)
   {
     ContentControl cc = new ContentControl();
     cc.ContentTemplate = dt;
     cc.Content = temp;
     myCanvas.Children.Add(cc);
   }
}

private void ChangeValues()
{
  // this simply changes the MyCustomPropery in each of the objects
}
```

The DataTemplate looks like this;

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate">
 <Canvas>
  <TextBlock Name="tb_debug" Text="{Binding Path=MyCustomProperty, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
   <TextBlock.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
     <BeginStoryboard>
      <Storyboard>
       <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tb_debug" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" From="0" To="350" Duration="0:0:1.6" />
      </Storyboard>
     </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
   </TextBlock.Triggers>
  </TextBlock>
 </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

It simply moves the textbox from the top to the bottom of the canvas when MyCustomProperty changes.

When the UserControl is Loaded, I call both AddItemsToCanvas() and ChangeValues(). The Text value updates and displays the correct value, but the Trigger doesn't fire (ie the TextBox doesn't move).
Any time after that, when I call ChangeValues() the Text updates AND the TextBox moves.

Why would the EventTrigger be failing that initial time?
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a small, yet *full* working example of the problem?  It'll be much easier then trying to figure out the problem from the bits and pieces...

Comment: I'm not sure if I can - this UserControl has about ~3000 lines of code, plus the class itself which is about the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `Binding.TargetUpdated` does not get called, but it could be only called when a the target is updated once already set and not when its first set (maybe).

But you could just add another `EventTrigger` on `TextBlock` `Loaded` in your `DataTremplate` to make sure it fires on `UserControl` Load.

Example:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="animation" >
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tb_debug" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" From="0" To="350" Duration="0:0:1.6" />
        </Storyboard>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <TextBlock Name="tb_debug" Text="{Binding Path=MyCustomProperty, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
           <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource animation}" />
            </EventTrigger>
               <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource animation}" />
            </EventTrigger>
           </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, that worked. I'll do some more testing today to try and work out exactly what's happening with that first event.

Comment: Do these animations have to be in a DataTemplate or can they be applied directly to a TextBlock Trigger?